# Can't login to jboss administrator console

Tags: jboss

I use EAP 6.2.0 GA EAP built from AS 7.3. In add-user.sh I wrote name and password, everything else I left by default. Then I run standalone.sh, go to localhost:8080 and try to get to administrative console using this user and password, but nothing happened, only cleaned fields. Please, tell me, what I missed?

Answer (score 1):

Admin console's URL is localhost:9990, 8080 is default port for your web application.
If your browser does not redirect you correctly, try localhost:9990/console/App.html

By the way, please make sure server is running properly, check standalone/log/server.log for warnings & errors.

Comment: brawser redirect correctly to link, that you give, and require user and password, but any user, that I registered in add-user previously, did not work. No error and warnings in log.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow @YShen answers. There are two types user available.

1. Management Users
2. Application Users

If you create Management Users and Using Management username and password to login admin console.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I resolve this problem: i added user in Jboss 7.1 and replace in 7.3 required files. After that everything works perfectly. But still i cant log in, when register user in 7.3. I have linux mint, maybe problem in this.